# Javascript Async issue with mongoDB functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am having an async issue where findLabels is firing before locateDoc and I can't make sense of how to handle these async issues. Currently I am only handling it with a setTimeout

```
router.get('/editing_station/:collection_name', function (req, res, next) {
  let collectionName = req.params.collection_name.slice(1, -1)
  db_trims.locateDoc(collectionName)
  db_label.locateDoc(collectionName)

  setTimeout(function(){ 
    db_label.findLabels((err, labels) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.sendStatus(500)
      }
      db_trims.findTrims((err, trims_) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.sendStatus(500)
        }
        res.render('editing_stream', {name: collectionName, label: labels, trims: trims_, trim: trimName})
      }) 
    }) 
   }, 1000);
})
```

I read I shouldn't nest call backs but I can't put together a functioning async waterfall or series

Comment: Why not use Promises or async/await

Comment: What is `locateDoc`, what does it do, where is it defined, how can you wait for its results?

Comment: "*I read I shouldn't nest call backs*" - it might look ugly, but there's nothing wrong with it. If it works, do it - and please post that version when asking about how to improve the code stylistically (using either the async.js library or promises).

Comment: @Bergi locateDoc simply sets a parameter collection name value in another js file which contains mongoDB query functions. If the value is not set, all the other query functions fail because "collection name cannot be a string"

Comment: @Bergi I am going to try it, but could you show me how you would do it? It will help me learn more about call backs, the documentation I am reading just isn't clicking.

Comment: What do you mean by "*locateDoc simply sets a parameter collection name value in another js file*"? That doesn't sound like it is doing anything asynchronous. Please post your implementation of `locateDoc` and `findLabels`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is `locateDoc` and what it returns, but assuming that it is some DB call or something and also it returns a `Promise`

You should change your code like this.

```
router.get('/editing_station/:collection_name', async function (req, res, next) {
    let collectionName = req.params.collection_name.slice(1, -1)
    await db_trims.locateDoc(collectionName)
    await db_label.locateDoc(collectionName)

    db_label.findLabels((err, labels) => {
        if (err) 
            return res.sendStatus(500);

        db_trims.findTrims((err, trims_) => {
            if (err)
                return res.sendStatus(500);         
            res.render('editing_stream', {name: collectionName, label: labels, trims: trims_})
        }) 
    }) 
})
```

Or better, if your functions with callbacks supports Promise way, you can do this too.

```
router.get('/editing_station/:collection_name', async function (req, res, next) {
    let collectionName = req.params.collection_name.slice(1, -1)
    try {
        await db_trims.locateDoc(collectionName)
        await db_label.locateDoc(collectionName)

        var labels = await db_label.findLabels()
        var trims_ = await db_trims.findTrims()
        res.render('editing_stream', {name: collectionName, label: labels, trims: trims_})
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you your first example worked! For those curious locatedoc is just a db call to get the name of a collection